# How much memory consumed by my object

Tags: c++

I want to know programmatic way to get the memory consumed by my user defined class.
Following is the declaration of the class

```
struct TrieNode {
    typedef std::map<char, TrieNode *> ChildType;
    std::string    m_word;
    bool      m_visited;
}
```

I have inserted around `264061` words into this `Trie`. After this when i do `sizeof(trieobject)` it just show me `32`. How do i know how much exact memory is used by such data structures.

Comment: You'll have to track the dynamic allocations. If you just rig up a simple test program, you can use `valgrind` to report heap usage. Otherwise you'll need to modify the allocators to make them print out statistics.

Comment: Constantinius, is a tree, perhaps words are in the child of the child.

Comment: Is this the actual code? The `TrieNode` in the code does not hold any children, it only defines  the type of the children, and has two members of types: `std::string` and `bool`

Comment: sizeof(std::string) + sizeof(bool) + m_word.capacity() + padding bytes or sizeof(trieobject) + m_word.capacity()

Answer (score 4):

I use

```
valgrind --tool=massif ./myprogram -opt arg1 arg2
ms_print massif.* | less -SR
```

for that. Sample output from [this page](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)

```
19.63^                                               ###                      
     |                                               #                        
     |                                               #  ::                    
     |                                               #  : :::                 
     |                                      :::::::::#  : :  ::               
     |                                      :        #  : :  : ::             
     |                                      :        #  : :  : : :::          
     |                                      :        #  : :  : : :  ::        
     |                            :::::::::::        #  : :  : : :  : :::     
     |                            :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  ::   
     |                        :::::         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : :: 
     |                     @@@:   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |                   ::@  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |                :::: @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |              :::  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |            ::: :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |         :::: : :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |       :::  : : :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |    :::: :  : : :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |  :::  : :  : : :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->KB     0                                                                   29.48

Number of snapshots: 25
 Detailed snapshots: [9, 14 (peak), 24]
```

The remainder of the log details the highest percentiles of memory allocations, you can specifically see what type of class takes what % of heap memory (and where the allocations originate in terms of call stack), e.g.:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10         10,080           10,080           10,000            80            0
 11         12,088           12,088           12,000            88            0
 12         16,096           16,096           16,000            96            0
 13         20,104           20,104           20,000           104            0
 14         20,104           20,104           20,000           104            0

99.48% (20,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->49.74% (10,000B) 0x804841A: main (example.c:20)
| 
->39.79% (8,000B) 0x80483C2: g (example.c:5)
| ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x80483E2: f (example.c:11)
| | ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x8048431: main (example.c:23)
| |   
| ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x8048436: main (example.c:25)
|   
->09.95% (2,000B) 0x80483DA: f (example.c:10)
  ->09.95% (2,000B) 0x8048431: main (example.c:23)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not so easy to do. First of all m_word is a string with variable size right? Internally the std::string holds an array of chars among other things. The same stands for std::map. I guess you could get a rough estimation based on the size of the map * TrieNode but this will be just a rough estimate.

I think some code profiling with an external tool would be of more help. Hell you can even use the task manager if you are out of any tools left :).

Answer (score 0):

Your "object size" is sizeof(std::string) + sizeof(bool) + m_word.capacity() + padding bytes or sizeof(trieobject) + m_word.capacity()

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code for GCC that I came up with that you can use in a test program where you only instantiate one object of your class and do some typical work with it. The code replaces the global `operator new()` and `operator delete()`; so it will only track allocations through `::new` expressions and the standard allocator, provided that the standard allocator itself uses `::operator new()` (this is the case for GCC).

Since we need to track the pointers and their allocations, we need a separate map for that, which of course cannot use the standard allocator itself; GCC's malloc-allocator comes to the rescue.

We use a statically initialized global to make the memory tracker print its data after `main` returns.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ext/malloc_allocator.h>

struct Memtrack
{
  typedef std::unordered_map<void*, std::size_t, std::hash<void*>,
     std::equal_to<void*>, __gnu_cxx::malloc_allocator<void*>> AllocMap;

  static int memtrack;
  static int memmax;
  static AllocMap allocs;

  Memtrack() { std::cout << "starting tracker: cur = " << memtrack  << ", max = " << memmax << ".\n"; }
  ~Memtrack() { std::cout << "ending tracker: cur = " << memtrack  << ", max = " << memmax << ".\n"; }

  static void track_new(std::size_t n, void * p)
  {
    memtrack += n;
    if (memmax < memtrack) memmax = memtrack;
    allocs[p] = n;

    std::cout << "... allocating " << n << " bytes...\n";
  }
  static void track_delete(void * p)
  {
    const int n = int(allocs[p]);
    memtrack -= n;
    std::cout << "... freeing " << n << " bytes...\n";
  }

} m;

int Memtrack::memtrack = 0;
int Memtrack::memmax = 0;
Memtrack::AllocMap Memtrack::allocs;

void * operator new(std::size_t n) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
  void * const p = std::malloc(n);
  Memtrack::track_new(n, p);
  return p;
}
void operator delete(void * p) throw()
{
  Memtrack::track_delete(p);
  std::free(p);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Beginning of main.\n";

  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;  // this piece of code
  m["hello"] = 4;                          // is a typical test for working
  m["world"] = 7;                          // with dynamic allocations

  std::cout << "End of main.\n";
}
```

Some typical output:

```
starting tracker: cur = 0, max = 0.
Beginning of main.
... allocating 48 bytes...
... allocating 12 bytes...
... allocating 12 bytes...
End of main.
... freeing 12 bytes...
... freeing 12 bytes...
... freeing 48 bytes...
ending tracker: cur = 0, max = 72.
```

Answer (score -1):

Trivial. **If** you have some time (which might be the case, if you are only interested in the size for debugging/optimising purposes). This approach might be unsuited for production code!

```
#include <malloc.h>

template <typename T> int objSize(T const* obj) {
  // instead of uordblks, you may be interested in 'arena', you decide!
  int oldSize = mallinfo().uordblks;
  T* dummy = new T(*obj);
  int newSize = mallinfo().uordblks;
  delete dummy;
  return newSize - oldSize;
}
```

Comment: `mallinfo` is not standard, `<malloc.h>` is a C header and `new` is not required to use `malloc()` underneath for the actual memory allocation.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I fail to find where the OP states the requirements you imply in your comment. But, to your points: So what if `malloc.h` is a C header, it is not at all uncommon to include C headers in C++. More to the point: `malloc` is insufficient, as you have to call the copy constructor (that's why I need `new`) so it will copy the members of `T`. As a matter of fact, if `malloc` **was** sufficient, you would know the required size a-priori which would make the whole exercise pointless, wouldn't it?